# Can I carry a NAS through airport security in the EU?

Tags: europe, airport-security, eu

I own a relatively small 4-bay [NAS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Network-attached_storage). Can it go through airport security within the European Union?

> Network-attached storage (NAS) is a file-level computer data storage server connected to a computer network providing data access to a heterogeneous group of clients

[image: NAS]

Comment: I added a description and a photo, if the NAS in question is the one with the mini drives (SSDs) then change the photo for a more accurate one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Of course you can.**

It doesn't fall under any of the categories of [restricted items](https://europa.eu/youreurope/citizens/travel/carry/luggage-restrictions/index_en.htm):

- It doesn't contain any liquids.
- It's neither sharp nor reasonably close to being a weapon.
- There are no flammable or explosive components or larger lithium batteries inside.

As far as security is concerned, it's no different from a metal box. You may just have to answer a few quick questions or take the drives out if the X-ray can't see through the whole thing well.

Comment: It needs however to fit in your hand luggage, the dimensions of which vary from airline to airline (and possibly class of travel and status). There may also be weight restrictions. Check with your airline for details.